# Data Access Object Primitive Type vs Object type?

Tags: java, database-design, object, primitive

Would like opinions on the best way to go.

As you can see int cannot be null.
Where as the object of Integer can.

Problem: Database values with a column that is number can be null or can contain a number.
When the database passes the value of null, then we receive and exception stating that 
"primitive values cannot be null"

But when we use Integer class, we are creating that object (which of course is bigger/bulkier than a primitive type int)

So that brings up to me a couple of choices.

1. Use Integer type.
2. Set Database column to "default"
3. Set int to default if there is something different in the database, then accept that

Any other suggestions?

Comment: If your data model includes a value represented by an integer primitive, then you should design your database to respect that design.  If you don't you just create problems for yourself that you don't need to.  Add a column constraint to the database that enforces that that particular column is NOT NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Hibernate (or similar ORM) and let the framework deal with the database directly. Then you can program it how you like, and not have to deal with converting.

Reinventing the wheel seldom works as well as just using someone else's wheel in the first place, especially when thousands of others already use the same wheel.

Comment: Indeed, but either way, primitive types cannot be null. so if your Data access object uses a primitive type. if your database does not have a value for it, then it throws an exception

Comment: Then you can't use a primitive type (if you need it to be null), can you? If you need a nullable primitive, either use a language that supports it, or use the nullable version of that primitive (Integer, in this case).

Comment: ahh, but that's what the question is... Should we use primitive type and set all the data base values to some sort of default, or would it be smarter to use Integer type on the Data Access Object (which is bulkier and takes more space)?

Comment: Model the data correctly. If null is null, then use null. Hacking together solutions to problems that have already been solved just makes more problems. If it isn't valid to store null values, then don't store them. If it is, then store them as null. The same holds true for the object model and the DB model. Don't worry about size until you can prove it's a problem. Maintainability is the #1 concern until other concerns have _shown_ themselves to mater more.

Comment: you make a good point. I guess more or less, im thinking of the bigger picture and not just simple ints, but further along as the software gets bigger.

Comment: Like I said...don't try to fix problems you don't have. If/when you have them, fix them then. Until then, work on what actually matters and keep things as simple as you can.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you must worry about Integer <-> int converting performance (100000000 opsec) if you query database (5000 op/sec). Use boxed types courageously.

Comment: Agreed. Processor time is cheap, and if you can show you run into an issue later, fix it then. Otherwise, you'll just have more problems to fix.

Answer (score 2):

My choices:

First- If it is possible and if it is logically ok to set a default in database (might be a FK to a ref table which has all values + a default).

Second - If first is not possible, I would use Integer objects without any reservation. I don't think you will have perf issues. The code will be clean but document in the variable that "can contain null and check for null while working on this variable".

I would always go for something which is more readable and understandable to keep the software maintainable and flexible.

Comment: Any time you are working with an Integer (opposed to an int), you need to assume it could be null, just like with _any_ object reference. If you don't, you are just asking for bugs.

Comment: But if there is invariant in the design which states that a specific object can't be null and it should always contain a valid object, Then I would not care about checking for null values. If it is null during runtime, let it fail with a NPE. we should fail fast.

But in his case, NULL is a valid value. So I've asked him to check for Nulls.

Comment: In general, I agree. However, for integers, specifically, the design could be improved by casting any invariant Integers to ints. When there is a simpler, more type-safe way to represent a constraint that lets the code speak for itself, it is the better way.

Comment: I like this response too, i agree, but I was checking for performance/space in the long run for numerous primitive types. Thanks guys